# Xamarin.Forms application hangs when using ResourceDictionary in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have Xamarin.Forms application where I want to show images from local database on a ListView. Images are stored in Base64 encoding, so I need to use a converter such described in an anwser to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305764/bind-base64-string-to-listview-in-xamarin-form). The problem I am facing is that if I include the **ContentPage.Resources** code in my XAML page after the **ContentPage** tag, the application will freeze on my phone, when I will try to open that page.

Resources code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ConverterBase64ImageSource x:Key="CustomImageConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

I have also created the local tag inside **ContentPage** tag as : `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"`

I have added the class **ConvertedBase64ImageSource** into the **Page.xaml.cs** file and the code of the converter is just like the one as provided in an awnser to the above linked question.

It seems like the XAML code breaks something in my application but I am not getting any errors, just application that becomes unresponsive and will not open that Page but instead display the OS message to force close the application. I am running the application in VS2015 in Debug mode, and the OnAppearing() method on that Page never hits my breakpoint.

Should I insert the **ContentPage.Resources** code somewhere else or am I missing something?

I am using Xamarin version **4.5.0.486**

Comment: Did you put in a breakpoint in the converter code? Does that get hit? The `ConverterBase64ImageSource` is actually in the `MyApp` namespace? Not the `MyApp.Converters` for instance?

Comment: Uff, that was it. I was using the root namescape not the one where converter was at. Strange thing is that I have the same "bug" for using translation service, but that somehow works. Would you be so kind to write your comment as an anwser, so I can accept it? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Done! Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double-check that the `ConverterBase64ImageSource` class is actually in the `MyApp` namespace? Not the `MyApp.Converters` for instance, then it won't work.

It shouldn't hang, but give you an error, but who knows!