# How to open base64 string attachments in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, attachment

I want to open a base64 string attachments on my Xamarin forms application. I have implemented it for pdf and image. But I couldn't get any solution for the following type Video,doc,txt.

Here is my code for pdf and image. I used syncfusion pdf reader for open pdf, is there any way to open it without using nuget. Please help me

```
   if (ContentType == "pdf")
       {
          var base64EncodedBytes =  System.Convert.FromBase64String(attachmentContent);
          PdfAttachement = new MemoryStream(base64EncodedBytes);
       }
   else if (ContentType=="image")
      {
       var imageString =attachmentContent;
       ImgAttachement = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(imageString)));
      }
```

Comment: The process to decode a Base64 attachment is the same regardless of the type of data in contains,

Comment: You can try to create a converter and use it after declaring it in xaml. You can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305764/bind-base64-string-to-listview-in-xamarin-form#:~:text=As%20per%20this%20forum%20thread%20you%20could%20create%20a%20converter%20for%20it.%20Just%20keep%20the%20Base64%20string%20as%20part%20of%20your%20Employee%20i.e.%20in%20the%20Base64Image%20property.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the video implementation like this

```
      public string MediaSource;
     private async Task VideoContentConvertion(byte [] decodedString,string fileName)
     {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(decodedString);

        string folder = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
        string videoFile = Path.Combine(folder,fileName);

        if (!File.Exists(videoFile))
        {
            using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(videoFile))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
            }
            savedFileName = videoFile;
        }
        MediaSource ="local/"+fileName;          
    }
```